# Need to replace the array keys in php

Tags: php

Here is the output array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [2] => 400
    [3] => 4000
    [4] => 40000
)
```

from the above array i need to replace the key in an orderly manner.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 400
    [2] => 4000
    [3] => 40000
)
```

then,
I need to add 2 values into above array. That values should any of the the values that array contain. Finally, i need the output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 400
    [2] => 4000
    [3] => 40000
    [4] => 40
    [5] => 4000
)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
//replace the key orderly
$new_array = array_values($old_array);
//add value
$new_array[] = $new_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems that you need to grab a random key twice after you corrected the array keys:

```
$arr=array ( 0 => 4, 2 => 400, 3 => 4000, 4 => 40000 );
echo "Before the array keys are sorted orderly:<br/>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";

$arr = array_values($arr);

for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
{
    $array_size=count($arr);
    $arr[]=$arr[mt_rand(0, $array_size-1)];
}
echo "After the sort and added values:<br/>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Copy and paste this code and run it and see if it produces the desired result.

**EDIT - EDIT - EDIT**

Please elaborate on the last step:

> then, I need to add 2 values into above array. That values should any
>   of the the values that array contain. Finally, i need the output like
>   this

My questions:

1. Can you put any value in the array or just the values that you already have in the array? The last 2 indexes contain the values "40" and "4000", but there is no 40 value in the whole array.